# listview webpart highlight list item

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010

I need help getting started. 
I have a listview webpart on my Wiki page. I would like to highlight the rows of the listview where the modified date is => 90 days old.

Can someone point me to a tutorial or something to get me started?

Answer (score 0):

**Conditional Formatting with SharePoint Designer**

The type of behavior you're looking for is known as **conditional formatting**. Ordinarily, you can add conditional formatting to a list view web part by editing the page it's on using SharePoint Designer; conditional formatting is one of the options that will appear in the ribbon menu when you click on the list view web part in SharePoint Designer.

However, you may not be able to edit a wiki page using SharePoint Designer.

**A JavaScript-based Alternative**

In your case, you may be better off doing something with JavaScript to find the modified field for each row, compare its value to today's date, and apply highlighting as necessary.

One thing you can do is take the code below, copy it into a text file, and save that text file into a library in your SharePoint site. Then add a content editor web part to your wiki page, edit its properties, and set the "content link" property of the web part to point to the URL of the text file. Save the page and get out of edit mode, and you'll see a link to add conditional formatting rules through the browser. This requires you to have access to create lists and list items on the site.

```html
<div id="_conditional_formatting_link" style="display:none; ">
 <div unselectable="on"  style="display:inline-block; user-select:none; cursor:pointer; padding: 3px; background-color:#9b9b9b; color:white; border:1px solid #888;" onclick="javascript:var rules = document.getElementById('_conditional_formatting'); if(rules.style.display == 'none'){rules.style.display = 'inline-block'}else{rules.style.display = 'none'}">
  Conditional Formatting
 </div>
</div>
<div id="_conditional_formatting" style="display:none;background-color:#dfdfdf; border: 1px solid black; width:95%; max-width:1100px;">
 <a style="border:0px;padding:5px;float:right;" title="Reapply Formatting" href="javascript:getConditions(false);">
  <img style="border:0px;" src="/_layouts/images/staticrefresh.gif"/>
 </a>
<ol id="_conditional_formatting_rules">
</ol>
<div style="text-align:right; ">
 <div id="_add_conditional_formatting_rule" unselectable="on" onclick="javascript: Add_Conditional_Formatting();" style="user-select:none; cursor:pointer; padding: 3px; margin: 3px; display:inline-block; background-color:#9b9b9b; border:1px solid #888; color:white;">Add Rule</div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
 function target() { var column; var comparison; var value; var style; var scope; var type; var id; var offset; } /* structure for storing formatting rules */
 var conditionalFormattingList = "Conditional Formatting";
 function getConditions(reloadRules) {
  /* if reloadRules, query the conditions list and get all the rules. Otherwise just reapply the ones in memory to the current document. */
  if (typeof (reloadRules) == "undefined") { reloadRules = true; }
  if (reloadRules) {
   while (document.getElementById("_conditional_formatting_rules").children.length > 0) { /* Clear out the currently displayed list of rules. */
    document.getElementById("_conditional_formatting_rules").removeChild(document.getElementById("_conditional_formatting_rules").children[0]);
   }
   this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
   var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(conditionalFormattingList);
   var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
   var folder = list.get_rootFolder();
   camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'URL\' /><Value Type=\'Text\'>' + document.location.pathname + '</Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\'Priority\' /><FieldRef Name=\'Name\' /></OrderBy></Query></View>');
   this.items = list.getItems(camlQuery);
   clientContext.load(list, 'EffectiveBasePermissions');
   clientContext.load(items);
   clientContext.load(folder);
  }
  this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
   Function.createDelegate(this,
    function () {
     /*Get the current user name from the drop-down box*/
     var Me = document.querySelector("#RibbonContainer-TabRowRight span[title='Open Menu'] [accesskey='W'] span").innerHTML;
     if (reloadRules) {
      var baseFormUrl = folder.get_serverRelativeUrl() + "/EditForm.aspx?ID=";
      /* Figure out if the current user has access to create or edit items on the Conditional Formatting list */
      var perms = list.get_effectiveBasePermissions();
      this.hasEdit = perms.has(SP.PermissionKind.editListItems);
      this.hasCreate = perms.has(SP.PermissionKind.addListItems);
      /* Fill an array with our formatting rules */
      this.targets = [];
      var itemEnumerator = this.items.getEnumerator();
      while (itemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
       var item = itemEnumerator.get_current();
       var targ = new target();
       targ.column = item.get_item("Column");
       targ.comparison = item.get_item("Comparison");
       targ.style = item.get_item("Style");
       targ.scope = item.get_item("Scope");
       targ.type = item.get_item("Type");
       targ.value = item.get_item("Value"); if (targ.value == null) { targ.value = ""; }
       targ.id = item.get_item("ID");
       targ.offset = item.get_item("Offset");
       targets.push(targ);
      }
     }
     if (!this.hasCreate) { document.getElementById("_add_conditional_formatting_rule").style.display = "none"; }
     for (var targetIterator = 0; targetIterator < targets.length; targetIterator++) {
      if (reloadRules) {
       var rulelist = document.getElementById("_conditional_formatting_rules");
       var ruletoadd = document.createElement("li");
       var comparisondisplay = targets[targetIterator].type.indexOf("Field") != -1 ? "value of the <b>" + targets[targetIterator].value + "</b> column" : "<b>'" + targets[targetIterator].value + "'</b>";
       if (targets[targetIterator].type == "Special" || targets[targetIterator].type == "Number") {
        if (targets[targetIterator].value.toString().toLowerCase() == "[me]") { comparisondisplay = "<b>[Me](" + Me + ")</b>"; }
        else { comparisondisplay = "<b>" + targets[targetIterator].value + "</b>"; }
       }
       if (targets[targetIterator].value == "") { comparisondisplay = "<b>(blank)</b>"; }
       if (targets[targetIterator].offset != null) {
        comparisondisplay += "<b>" + (targets[targetIterator].offset < 0 ? " " : " +") + targets[targetIterator].offset + "</b>"
       }
       var editLink = this.hasEdit ? "<div style='display:inline-block;cursor:pointer;' onclick='SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogOpen(" + '"' + baseFormUrl + targets[targetIterator].id + '&Source=' + document.location.pathname + '"' + ",{},refreshPageConditions); '>" + "<img src='/_layouts/images/EDITITEM.GIF' style='vertical-align:middle;' title='Customize' alt='Customize'/>" + "&nbsp;</div>" : "";
       ruletoadd.innerHTML = editLink + "When <b>" + targets[targetIterator].column + "</b> "
        + targets[targetIterator].comparison + " " + comparisondisplay
        + ", apply {" + (targets[targetIterator].style == null ? "remove all formatting" : "<span style='" + targets[targetIterator].style + "'>" + targets[targetIterator].style + "</span>") + "} to the <b>" + targets[targetIterator].scope + "</b>" + ((targets[targetIterator].scope != "Cell" && targets[targetIterator].scope != "Row") ? " column" : "");
       rulelist.appendChild(ruletoadd);
      }
      var tables = document.querySelectorAll("table.ms-listviewtable"); /* Should get all the list view web parts on the page. */
      var t_i = 0;
      while (t_i < tables.length) {
       var columnIndex = null; /* Index of the column to compare against */
       var valueIndex = null; /* Index of a second column from which to pull the value to compare */
       var styleTargetIndex = null; /* Index of a column to apply formatting to */
       var thisTable = tables[t_i];
       var headings = thisTable.rows[0].cells;
       var h_i = 0;
       while (h_i < headings.length) { /* Check all the column headings... */
        var thisHeading = headings[h_i].querySelector("div:first-child");
        if (thisHeading != null) {
         /* In Internet Explorer, the headings have a DisplayName attribute you can grab. If that's not there, just grab the innerText or textContent */
         var dispname = thisHeading.DisplayName ? thisHeading.DisplayName : (thisHeading.innerText ? thisHeading.innerText : thisHeading.textContent);
         dispname = dispname.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');/* removes leading and trailing whitespace */
         if (targets[targetIterator].scope != "Cell" && targets[targetIterator].scope != "Row") {
          /*If the scope isn't Cell or Row, see if this is the cell to which the formatting should applied */
          if (dispname == targets[targetIterator].scope) { styleTargetIndex = h_i; }
         }
         if (targets[targetIterator].type.indexOf("Field") != -1) {
          /*If the value type is a Field, check to see if this is the field whose value we care about */
          if (dispname == targets[targetIterator].value.toString()) { valueIndex = h_i; }
         }
         if (dispname == targets[targetIterator].column) { columnIndex = h_i; }
        }
        h_i += 1;
       }
       if (columnIndex != null) { /* If we found a matching heading, let's try to apply the rules... */
        var rows = thisTable.rows;
        for (var i = (rows.length > 0 ? 1 : 0) ; i < rows.length; i++) {
         var cells = rows[i].children;
         if (cells.length <= columnIndex) { continue }
         var innerLink = cells[columnIndex].querySelector("a"); /* I want to specifically target links so that we can change their text color if necessary */
         /* Populate valueToEval with the text value of the current cell, or its inner link if it has one */
         var valueToEval = cells[columnIndex].innerText ? (innerLink != null ? innerLink.innerText : cells[columnIndex].innerText) : (innerLink != null ? innerLink.textContent : cells[columnIndex].textContent);
         if (typeof (valueToEval) == "undefined") { valueToEval = "" } /* Treat empties as blanks */
         var listValueToCompareAgainst = null;
         if (valueIndex != null) { /* valueIndex only has a value if we need to grab the comparison value from another column on the list */
          valueLink = cells[valueIndex].querySelector("a");
          listValueToCompareAgainst = cells[valueIndex].innerText ? (valueLink != null ? valueLink.innerText : cells[valueIndex].innerText) : (valueLink != null ? valueLink.textContent : cells[valueIndex].textContent);
         }
         var needsStyling = false;
         switch (targets[targetIterator].type) {
          case "Number":
           if (!isNaN(Number(valueToEval))) {
            valueToEval = Number(valueToEval);
           }
           if (!isNaN(Number(targets[targetIterator].value))) {
            targets[targetIterator].value = Number(targets[targetIterator].value);
           }
           break;
          case "Date":
           valueToEval = new Date(valueToEval);
           targets[targetIterator].value = new Date(targets[targetIterator].value);
           if (targets[targetIterator].offset != null) {
            targets[targetIterator].value.setDate(targets[targetIterator].value.getDate() + Number(targets[targetIterator].offset));
           }
           break;
          case "Text": /* Already covered, bro */ break;
          case "Date Field":
           valueToEval = new Date(valueToEval);
           targets[targetIterator].value = new Date(listValueToCompareAgainst);
           if (targets[targetIterator].offset != null) {
            targets[targetIterator].value.setDate(targets[targetIterator].value.getDate() + Number(targets[targetIterator].offset));
           }
           break;
          case "Text Field": targets[targetIterator].value = listValueToCompareAgainst; break;
          case "Number Field":
           if (!isNaN(Number(listValueToCompareAgainst))) {
            targets[targetIterator].value = listValueToCompareAgainst;
            if (targets[targetIterator].offset != null) {
             targets[targetIterator].value += Number(targets[targetIterator].offset);
            }
           }
           if (!isNaN(Number(valueToEval))) {
            valueToEval = Number(valueToEval);
           }
           break;
          case "Special":
           if (targets[targetIterator].value.toLowerCase) {
            if (targets[targetIterator].value.toLowerCase() == "[me]") { targets[targetIterator].value = Me }
            else if (targets[targetIterator].value.toLowerCase().indexOf("[today]") != -1) {
             var dateDifference = Number(targets[targetIterator].value.toLowerCase().replace("[today]", "").replace(" ", "").replace("+", ""));
             targets[targetIterator].value = new Date();
             if (!isNaN(dateDifference)) { targets[targetIterator].value.setDate(targets[targetIterator].value.getDate() + dateDifference); }
             if (targets[targetIterator].offset != null) {
              targets[targetIterator].value.setDate(targets[targetIterator].value.getDate() + Number(targets[targetIterator].offset));
             }
             valueToEval = new Date(valueToEval);
            }
           } else { valueToEval = new Date(valueToEval); }
           break;
         }
         switch (targets[targetIterator].comparison) {
          case "Greater Than or Equal To": needsStyling = (valueToEval >= targets[targetIterator].value); break;
          case "Greater Than": needsStyling = (valueToEval > targets[targetIterator].value); break;
          case "Less Than or Equal To": needsStyling = (valueToEval <= targets[targetIterator].value); break;
          case "Less Than": needsStyling = (valueToEval < targets[targetIterator].value); break;
          case "Equal To": needsStyling = (valueToEval == targets[targetIterator].value); break;
          case "Not Equal To": needsStyling = (valueToEval != targets[targetIterator].value); break;
          case "Contains": needsStyling = (valueToEval.indexOf(targets[targetIterator].value) != -1); break;
          case "Does Not Contain": needsStyling = (valueToEval.indexOf(targets[targetIterator].value) == -1); break;
         }
         if (needsStyling) {
          var links;
          if (targets[targetIterator].scope != "Row") {
           var targetIndex = (styleTargetIndex != null) ? styleTargetIndex : columnIndex;
           cells[targetIndex].setAttribute("style", targets[targetIterator].style);
           links = cells[targetIndex].querySelectorAll("a");

          } else {
           rows[i].setAttribute("style", targets[targetIterator].style);
           for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
            cells[j].setAttribute("style", targets[targetIterator].style);
           }
           links = rows[i].querySelectorAll("a");
          }
          for (var j = 0; j < links.length; j++) {
           if (links[j].title != "Open Menu") {
            links[j].setAttribute("style", targets[targetIterator].style);
            links[j].style.backgroundColor = "";
           }
           links[j].style.border = "0px";
          }
         }
        }
       }
       t_i += 1;
      }
     }
     document.getElementById("_conditional_formatting_link").style.display = "inline-block";
    }
   ),
   Function.createDelegate(this,
    function (sender, args) { /* There was an error accessing the list. Time to create it! */
     var lci = new SP.ListCreationInformation();
     lci.set_title(conditionalFormattingList);
     lci.set_templateType(SP.ListTemplateType.genericList);
     var condition_list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().add(lci);
     clientContext.load(condition_list);
     /* Drop the Title field */
     var colTitle = condition_list.get_fields().getByTitle("Title");
     colTitle.set_required(false);
     colTitle.set_hidden(true);
     colTitle.update();
     condition_list.update();
     /* Add New Fields */
     var colColumn = condition_list.get_fields().addFieldAsXml('<Field Description=\'The column to compare (must be visible on the page)\' DisplayName=\'Column\' Type=\'Text\'/>', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);
     var colComparison = condition_list.get_fields().addFieldAsXml('<Field Description=\'\' Type=\'Choice\' DisplayName=\'Comparison\' Format=\'Dropdown\' FillInChoice=\'FALSE\'><Default>Equal To</Default><CHOICES><CHOICE>Greater Than</CHOICE><CHOICE>Greater Than or Equal To</CHOICE><CHOICE>Equal To</CHOICE><CHOICE>Less Than or Equal To</CHOICE><CHOICE>Less Than</CHOICE><CHOICE>Not Equal To</CHOICE><CHOICE>Contains</CHOICE><CHOICE>Does Not Contain</CHOICE></CHOICES></Field>', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);
     var colValue = condition_list.get_fields().addFieldAsXml('<Field Description=\'The value or the name of a column to compare against\' DisplayName=\'Value\' Type=\'Text\'/>', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);
     var colType = condition_list.get_fields().addFieldAsXml('<Field Description=\'Indicate the type of value you are comparing against. Choose Special if using the [Me] or [Today] placeholders.\' Type=\'Choice\' DisplayName=\'Type\' Format=\'Dropdown\' FillInChoice=\'FALSE\'><Default>Text</Default><CHOICES><CHOICE>Date</CHOICE><CHOICE>Number</CHOICE><CHOICE>Text</CHOICE><CHOICE>Date Field</CHOICE><CHOICE>Number Field</CHOICE><CHOICE>Text Field</CHOICE><CHOICE>Special</CHOICE></CHOICES></Field>');
     var colOffset = condition_list.get_fields().addFieldAsXml('<Field Description=\'Optionally specify a number to offset the value by when comparing against a number or date.\' DisplayName=\'Offset\' Type=\'Number\' />', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);
     var colStyle = condition_list.get_fields().addFieldAsXml('<Field NumLines=\'4\' Description=\'The CSS to apply to when the condition is met. Leave blank to remove formatting. Example syntax: background-color:darkred; color:white; font-weight:bold;\' DisplayName=\'Style\' Type=\'Note\' />', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);
     var colScope = condition_list.get_fields().addFieldAsXml('<Field Description=\'The scope to which the style should be applied. Choose Row, Cell, or specify a column name.\' Type=\'Choice\' DisplayName=\'Scope\' Format=\'Dropdown\' FillInChoice=\'TRUE\'><Default>Cell</Default><CHOICES><CHOICE>Cell</CHOICE><CHOICE>Row</CHOICE></CHOICES></Field>', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);
     var colPriority = condition_list.get_fields().addFieldAsXml('<Field Description=\'Priority determines which styles are applied in case of overlapping conditions. Higher numbers are applied later.\' DisplayName=\'Priority\' Type=\'Number\' />', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);
     var colUrl = condition_list.get_fields().addFieldAsXml('<Field Description=\'Page where this rule should be applied\' DisplayName=\'URL\' Type=\'Text\'/>', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);
     clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
      Function.createDelegate(this, function () { getConditions(); }),
      Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) { document.getElementById("_conditional_formatting").innerHTML = ("An error occcurred while trying to apply conditional formatting to the list for you. Error details: " + args.get_message() + " " + args.get_stackTrace()); document.getElementById("_conditional_formatting_link").style.display = "inline-block"; }));
    }
   ));
 }
 /* This method is called when the Add Rule button is clicked. */
 function Add_Conditional_Formatting() {
  /* Create a new item with only the URL and Priority fields filled out */
  var currUrl = document.location.pathname;
  var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
  var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
  var newItem = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(conditionalFormattingList).addItem(itemCreateInfo);
  newItem.set_item('URL', currUrl);
  /* Give the new item a priority that will put it at the end of the list. This is kind of a hack since the highest priority is not necessarily the rulecount. */
  newItem.set_item('Priority', document.getElementById("_conditional_formatting_rules").children.length + 1);
  newItem.update();
  clientContext.load(newItem);
  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function () {
   getConditions(); /* Reload to refresh the rules list after adding the item */
  }), Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) { alert(args.get_message()); }));
 }

 /* This method is called when the Edit Item dialog box is closed. It refreshes the page it the item was saved. */
 function refreshPageConditions(result) { if (result != SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel) { window.location.replace(document.location.href) } }

 ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
  getConditions();
  /* If there are any collapsible sections on the page, keep checking to see whether formatting needs to be reapplied */
  this.TableRowCount = 0;

  if (document.querySelector("img[alt='expand']") != null) {
   setInterval(function () {
    var tempTableRowCount = document.querySelectorAll("tr").length;
    if (tempTableRowCount != this.TableRowCount) {
     /* Only reapply formatting if the count of table rows is different than it was previously */
     this.TableRowCount = tempTableRowCount;
     getConditions(false) /* Passing false reapplies loaded rules without re-querying the SharePoint list */
    }
   }, 1000)
  }
 }, "SP.JS");
</script>
```

You would then want to add a rule that looks like this:
[image: Conditional formatting example screenshot]

That script handles the nitty gritty tasks of creating a list of conditional formatting rules, checking those rules against list view web parts on the page, and applying them when the page loads. So all you need to do then is add the rules!

Comment: I guess I will have to jump into this and figure it out. I discovered that I am not able to do anything via SPD because once I place the masterpage on my work it strips everything out and the admins will not let us mere mortal Site Collection Admins have access rights to the master.